# Is it possible to change turtle's pen stroke?

Tags: python, graphics, graph, turtle-graphics

I need to draw a bar graph using Python's turtle graphics and I figured it would be easier to simply make the pen a thick square so I could draw the bars like that and not have to worry about making dozens of rectangles and filling them in.

When I set the turtle shape using `turtle.shape('square')` though, it only changes the appearance of the pen but has no effect on the actual drawing:

[image]

Is there a way to make turtle actually draw a rectangular stroke, whether that be through built-in methods or through modifying the turtle file?

I DON'T want rounded edges, like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turtle.pensize(int) where the argument is the size in PX?

Comment: Yes, this simply makes a larger ellipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question asked in the title: **No, it is not possible to change the pen stroke directly** *(see [cdlane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42174223/2662227) for a possible way to do it by modifying the hardcoded values from `tkinter`)*.

I did find a workaround for the use case presented in the question body, however.

A custom pen shape (in this case, representing the exact shape and size of the bar) can be registered like this:

```
screen.register_shape("bar", ((width / 2, 0), (-width / 2, 0), (-width / 2, height), (width / 2, height)))`
```

We can then simply loop through each bar, update the pen shape with the new values, and use `turtle.stamp` to stamp the completed bars onto the graph, no drawing required.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like changing the shape of the pen stroke itself isn't possible. `turtle.shape('square')` only changes the shape of the turtle, not the pen stroke. I suggest lowering the pen size, and creating a function to draw a rectangle. You could use this do draw the bars.

Comment: `turtle.shape("square")` works as long as you use `turtle.stamp()`--see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42174223/6243352).

Answer (score 3):

I've two solutions to this problem that I've used in various programs.

The first is a variation on your stamp solution.  Rather than use `screen.register_shape()` to register a custom polygon for each line, use a square turtle and for each line `turtle.turtlesize()` it into the rectangle you want to stamp:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

STAMP_SIZE = 20  # size of the square turtle shape

WIDTH, LENGTH = 25, 125

yertle = Turtle(shape="square")
yertle.penup()

yertle.turtlesize(WIDTH / STAMP_SIZE, LENGTH / STAMP_SIZE)

yertle.goto(100 + LENGTH//2, 100)  # stamps are centered, so adjust X

yertle.stamp()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

My other solution, when I need to *draw* instead of *stamp*, is to reach into turtle's tkinter underpinning and modify turtle's hardcoded line end shape itself:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import tkinter as _

_.ROUND = _.BUTT

WIDTH, LENGTH = 25, 125

yertle = Turtle()
yertle.width(WIDTH)
yertle.penup()

yertle.goto(100, 100)

yertle.pendown()

yertle.forward(LENGTH)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple stamps like so:

```
import turtle

turtle.shape("square")
for count in range(x):
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.forward(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an official way to do that.
you can use the turtle.shape() function to set a shape.
and the shapes can be registered by yourself by using the screen.register_shape('your file name') function.

1. get a .gif file that is your intended shape, whose name is 'xxx.gif'.
2. put this gif file into the same file as your py code file.
3. use screen(your screen variable).register_shape('xxx.gif')
4. turtle(your turtle variable).shape('xxx.gif'), the suffix must be followed.

then, it's done.

Comment: btw, use the stamp() function instead of letting the turtle draw to make your traces.

Comment: If you read my text carefully...

Comment: I need to clarify that this answer is not exactly the same as the accepted answer, which didn't involve the registration of a .gif file. And importing a .gif file is definitely making the shape more flexible.