# Different lines of color in a hexagon

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was just wondering on how to get different colors on each line of the hexagon. Below I have the desired output and input.

Output Right Now - [Link to output right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az12V.jpg)

Output I want - [Link to output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL5Nn.jpg)

```
import turtle as trtl

colors = ["#9c2921", "#cf8e04","#f5d905",]

#--------------------
num_sides = int(input("Enter the number of sides(Enter 6 to get the output of the real image): "))

if num_sides == 6:
  print("Desired artwork is displayed")

side_length = 25
circumradius = side_length


angle = 360/len(colors)
trtl.width(10)



for color in colors:
    trtl.color(color)
    trtl.pensize(10)
    for move_turtle in range(1):
      trtl.penup()
      trtl.sety(-circumradius)
      trtl.pendown()
      trtl.circle(circumradius, steps = num_sides)

      circumradius *= 2

trtl.hideturtle()
```

Comment: You're drawing the shape in one call so it can only be one color. For separate colors, you need to draw each side separately.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, your program looks like code I wrote in response to your previous question that has neither been accepted nor upvoted.  Moving on:

Given this `circle()` and a fat pen based approach for drawing the hexagons, I believe this is about the best you can do:

```
import turtle
from itertools import cycle

COLORS = ["#9c2921", "#f5d905", "#cf8e04",]
NUM_SIDES = 6
SIDE_LENGTH = 50
PEN_WIDTH = 25

circumradius = SIDE_LENGTH

turtle.width(PEN_WIDTH)

color = cycle(COLORS)

for _ in range(4):

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-circumradius)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(NUM_SIDES):
        turtle.color(next(color))
        turtle.circle(circumradius, extent=360/NUM_SIDES, steps=1)

    circumradius += PEN_WIDTH*2

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

[image]

To get closer to the target image, you'd need to draw the individual segments of the hexagon (circle) as trapezoids.

```
import turtle
from itertools import cycle

COLORS = ["#9c2921", "#f5d905", "#cf8e04",]
NUM_SIDES = 6
SIDE_LENGTH = 50
PEN_WIDTH = 30

circumradius = SIDE_LENGTH

turtle.width(1)
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

color = cycle(COLORS)

for _ in range(4):

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-circumradius)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(NUM_SIDES):
        turtle.color(next(color))
        turtle.circle(circumradius, extent=360/NUM_SIDES, steps=1)
        turtle.right(90)

        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(PEN_WIDTH/2)
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.forward(circumradius + PEN_WIDTH/2)
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.forward(PEN_WIDTH/2)
        turtle.end_fill()

        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(PEN_WIDTH/2)
        turtle.right(60)
        turtle.forward(circumradius - PEN_WIDTH/2)
        turtle.right(60)
        turtle.forward(PEN_WIDTH/2)
        turtle.end_fill()

        turtle.left(90)

    circumradius += PEN_WIDTH*2

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

[image]